# Beeware Toga Selection widget: unable to change text size

Tags: python, text, widget, selection, beeware

In my `Beeware app` I am trying to use the `Selection widget` according to https://toga.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/widgets/selection.html setting the value of the the `font_size` parameter. To test it I use the simple script attached below. The widget works correctly, but the font size remains small and `is not affected` no matter what value I set. Any suggestion or hint how to make it work will be much appreciated

```
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW


class HelloWorld(toga.App):
    def startup(self):
        self.selection=toga.Selection(style=Pack(font_size=30),\
                items=["title", "message","sound"],on_select=self.func1)
        main_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))
        main_box.add(self.selection)

        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box

    def func1(self,widget):
        print(self.selection.value)
        return 

def main():
    return HelloWorld()
```

Comment: As I mentioned in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77326241), the development version has many bug fixes, so you should try that if you haven't already.

Comment: Even on the development version, there's a [known bug](https://github.com/beeware/toga/pull/2130) with changing Selection fonts on Android, so you'll have to live with that for now. Or if you're running on another platform, please edit your question to say which one.

Comment: @mhsmith thank you, I am constantly working with the modified pyproject.toml you suggested, and with the dev version